# HTML / Javascript Function Not Calling

Tags: javascript, function, button, submit

This code that I wrote is meant to call the `calculateInterest` function and return false. However, the page does not appear to call the function or return false. Thank you for the help.

HTML

```
<form onsubmit="return calculateInterest(); return false;"  id="interest_calc" name="interest_calc"  method = "get";> 
  ...
  <input type="submit" id="calculate" value="Calculate">
  <input type="button" id="calculate" value="test" onclick="return calculateInterest();">
</form>
```

JS

```
var $ = function (id) 
{
  return document.getElementById(id);
};//DOM function
...

//DEBUG alert (iPercentage);
var calculateInterest; = function () 
{
  alert ("function called");
  return false
};
```

Comment: Remove semicolon. *`var calculateInterest; = function ()`*

Comment: Check this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted

Answer (score 0):

Remove the unnecessary  `;` on script .And no need a `return false`  on `submit` function call in html.Because its already there in `calculateinterest` function

```js
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

var calculateInterest = function() {

  alert("function called");

  return false

};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return calculateInterest()" id="interest_calc" name="interest_calc" method="get" ;>



  ...



  <input type="submit" id="calculate" value="Calculate">

  <input type="button" id="calculate" value="test" onclick="return calculateInterest();">


</form>
```